# Mantle:cannot find protocol declaration, 'MTLJSONSerializing'

Tags: iphone, cocoapods, github-mantle

I installed 'Mantle' using coco pod.  But when I try to use it in my model, it is getting this error.

/Users/bgbb/Developer/experimental/MantleTest/MantleTest/TestMTL.h:11:32: Cannot find protocol declaration for 'MTLJSONSerializing'

```
#import "MTLModel.h"

@interface TestMTL : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>

@end
```

This is my podfile.

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

pod 'Mantle', '1.1.2'
```

I am not sure what I am missing.  Any clue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The protocol declaration for `MTLJSONSerializing` is in `MTLJSONAdapter.h`

While you could fix this by adding another import (`#import "MTLJSONAdapter.h"`), it's generally better to import a library or framework's umbrella header.

You should import Mantle's umbrella header to get access to all of the public interfaces in Mantle:

```
#import <Mantle/Mantle.h>

@interface TestMTL : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>

@end
```